# Copy sent mail to shared mailbox

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, mailbox, share

We have a Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 running. I have granted certain users Full Access Permission to a specific mailbox. This mailbox also contains contacts, shared by all users who have access to that mailbox.

If a User clicks on a contact in that mailbox and sends a mail, the mail appears in the Users own sent Mails Folder.

I am looking for a solution where mails to one of the shared contacts mail adress will also appear in that mailboxes sent or inbox folder, so everyone can track what messages have been sent.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has released an Outlook 2007 hotfix package dated June 30, 2009 to resolve certain issues and this issue is addressed in that list

1. Hotfix: Description of the Outlook 2007 hotfix package (Outlook.msp): June 30, 2009
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970944/
2. Set below registry key to enable this functionality.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preferences] 
"DelegateSentItemsStyle"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 0):

That's the default way when working with Outlook/Exchange and shared mailboxes.

Check out [this fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972148).